# Linux bash script to find and delete oldest file with special characters and whitespaces in a directory tree if condtion is met

Tags: linux, bash

I need some help building a linux bash script to find and delete oldest file with special characters and white spaces in a directory tree if condtion is met.

I have been searching the forum for questions like this and thanks to users here I came with output as seen under. So far I can't figure out how to pipe the output filename to rm, so that it is being deleted.

The goal is to check if hdd is running full, and if so delete the oldest file until free-space requirement is met. The problem is, that the filenames are filled with special characters and white-spaces...

This is what I ended up with (thanks to users here!):

```
find /mnt/volume0/recordings/ -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | head -q -n 1 | cat
```

Which gives output:

```
2016-03-11+19:21:44.2814042100 /mnt/volume0/recordings/some folder (R)/some filename (R)2016-03-1119-00.ts
```

How can I get then pick out the full path name to the file with all special charcters and whitespaces piped to rm for it to delete the file?

Here is the output from the answered post:

```
root@SERVER:~# find /mnt/volume0/recordings/ -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -d |  head -n1
2016-03-11+19:21:44.2814042100 /mnt/volume0/recordings/VIDEO_FILE (R)/VIDEO_FILE (R)2016-03-1119-00.ts
root@SERVER:~# find /mnt/volume0/recordings/ -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -d |  head -n1 | xargs -I{} echo rm -f "{}"
rm -f 2016-03-11+19:21:44.2814042100 /mnt/volume0/recordings/VIDEO_FILE (R)/VIDEO_FILE (R)2016-03-1119-00.ts
root@SERVER:~# find /mnt/volume0/recordings/ -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -d |  head -n1 | xargs -I{} rm -f "{}"
root@SERVER:~# find /mnt/volume0/recordings/ -type f -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -d |  head -n1
2016-03-11+19:21:44.2814042100 /mnt/volume0/recordings/VIDEO_FILE (R)/VIDEO_FILE (R)2016-03-1119-00.ts
```

EDIT: output from anwered post1. Still not working...

EDIT2: output from sorontar suggestion, still not working, new suggestion only gives dir name, not file...

NEW output:

```
root@SERVER:~# find /mnt/volume0/recordings/ -type f -printf '%T+ %p\0' | sort -zk1,1 | head -n1 -z | cut -zd ' ' -f2
/mnt/volume0/recordings/Parneviks
root@SERVER:~# find /mnt/volume0/recordings/ -type f -printf '%T+ %p\0' | sort -zk1,1 | head -n1 -z | cut -zd ' ' -f2 | xargs -0 -I{} echo rm -f "{}"
rm -f /mnt/volume0/recordings/Parneviks
```

While the oldest file is this:

```
root@SERVER:~# find /mnt/volume0/recordings/ -type f -printf '%T+ %p\0' | sort -zk1,1 | head -n1 -z
2016-03-11+19:21:44.2814042100 /mnt/volume0/recordings/Parneviks (R)/Parneviks (R)2016-03-1119-00.ts
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT3:
-f2- instead of -f2 made it working. Thank you all!

Correct line is:

```
find /mnt/volume0/recordings/ -type f -printf '%T+ %p\0' | sort -zk1,1 | head -n1 -z | cut -zd ' ' -f2- | xargs -0 -I{} rm -f "{}"
```

Comment: I'm glad your problem's been solved! That said, for the future, answers shouldn't be edited into questions -- keeping the question and the answer separate means that the community can vote for each on its own individual merits. (While you have a good answer here, if you *didn't* have any good answer, it would be better to add your own answer *as an answer* than to edit it into the question).

Comment: (Similarly, since we actually have an interface with full diff-style edit history for those who care, local preference is to have questions and answers written and edited to read as clearly as possible to someone who hasn't seen them before, vs having edits called out at the end).

Comment: OK, sorry. This was my first post. I just tried to make it clear what solved the problem. I will keep that in mind for the future. Again a big thank you to all contributors.

Comment: No problem at all -- everywhere has their own culture and expectations, and while a lot of what expectations are documented in [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), there are a lot of things where consensus is only on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) if even there. Welcome to StackOverflow -- I hope it's a useful resource for you for a long time to come!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to process files with spaces, new lines and any special characters, you must consider using a null `\0` as the limit for file names, like this:

```
dir=/mnt/volume0/recordings

find "$dir"/ -type f -printf '%T+ %p\0' | 
    sort -zk1,1 | 
    head -n1 -z |
    cut -zd ' ' -f2- |
    xargs -0 echo rm -f --
```

This will find files in a dir and forcefully will remove the oldest file (only one) (if the echo is removed, test it before actually using it).

Comment: Thank you for your input! 
I will use null operator.

See edit, for output, your suggestion only outputs directory name of the file unfortunately.
The files will be in sub folders in a directory tree, I don't know if that is the problem?

Comment: `cut -f2` isn't going to work if there are spaces in the filename. Perhaps you meant `-f2-` rather than `-f2`?

Comment: (I would advise against using `-I{}` when not necessary, though -- `xargs -0 rm -f --` will do the job with fewer `rm` invocations and will avoid all the legacy restrictions that `xargs -I` brings with it).

Comment: @sorontar, I hope I'm not overreaching by editing code -- feel free to back the change out and come up with an alternate fix if this was unwelcome.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  Not at all, feel free to update (this and future answers as well) as you find it is useful. There is always the chance to edit even more, if needed. Thanks.