# Set modified date of a file to the oldest in a directory

Tags: bash, shell

I know the command `touch file_example` to set the file `file_example` to the newest modified file (which appears at the bottom when I do a `ls -lrt`).

Now, I would like to execute a short command to set the file `file_example` to the oldest file in a given directory, i.e which appears on first line when I do a `ls -lrt`.

Is it possible to make it with a quick command ?

Comment: If you have `stat` on your system, you could use it on your oldest file,  parse its output to get the exact time stamp, and then use `touch -d` or `touch -t` to set this time stamp on the file you want to apply it. With `-t` you can set the timestamp only to the granularity of seconds, so it will likely not be **exactly** as the reference time stamp.

Comment: `touch file_example` sets the access and modification time for `file_example` to the current time, not the most recently modified file.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41004647/3776858 Replace `rm -f --` with `touch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over all files, and whenever you find one that's older than `file_example`, you can update `file_example`:

```sh
for f in ./*; do
    # Skip directories
    [[ -d $f ]] && continue

    # Compare and update
    [[ $f -ot file_example ]] && touch file_example -r "$f"
done
```

If you want to include hidden files, you can either loop with `for f in ./* ./.*`, or use `shopt -s dotglob` first.

This can be packaged in a shell function:

```sh
settooldest() {
    local file=$1
    local dir=$2
    local f
    for f in "$dir"/*; do
        [[ -d $f ]] && continue
        [[ $f -ot $file ]] && touch "$file" -r "$f"
    done
}
```

Which is called like

```sh
settooldest file_example path/to/dir
```